# Highspeed sync using PocketWizards and Nikon flashes

Tags: nikon, flash, off-camera-flash, high-speed-sync, pocket-wizard

I have set the camera on **HighSpeedSync** by going to flash setting in camera and setting the speed to 1/350 sec. ( on `Nikon D-810`)

Then I researched a little and looks like there is not a setting for Nikon Flashes - `SB 910` in my case - to put them in High Speed Sync and we just set it in camera which I did above.

Then I put the **PocketWizard Plus III** on `HSR` mode which their manual says it is for high speed sync mode.

But when I shot at `1/400sec`, I got that black curtain thing in the image.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HSR isn't HSS.**

To quote from [the PocketWizard PlusIII's website](http://plusiii.pocketwizard.com/):

> 7. **HIGH SPEED RECEIVE**
>      Normally, the Plus III is capable of triggering lights or cameras at a sustained rate of up to 12 frames per second (FPS), a standard for PocketWizard radios. Set the Plus III to High Speed Receive Mode (HSR) and trigger at rates up to 14.5 FPS, beyond the capability of most of today's cameras. This mode can also help high FPS triggering compatibility for any flash.

It looks as though HSR is if you want to *burst* shoot and have the flash syncing keeping up with the frame rate, but is not HSS for higher shutter speeds. The Plus III, being a manual-only trigger, cannot communicate the sync timing/pulses required for HSS/FP.  You'd need the Flex/Mini units for HSS communication.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so with PlusIII I can still shoot in burst mode of the camera as long as I am under 250sec and cannot shoot in burst mode if I am higher speed like 400sec.

Comment: Yup. The Plus IIIs won't let you go past your max. sync speed.